# Why am I getting an error from implementing GestureDetector?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement GuestureDetector but I get an error. The "OnGestureListener" and OnDoubleTapListener are both in red and android studio is saying "cannot resolve symbol 'OnGestureListener' . I have tried a few others but it doesn't seem to work. How do I fix this?

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
```

Comment: make sure your import statement. as well as immplements method's of a Gesture Class

Comment: @Sagar I need to have a separate Gesture Class?

Comment: then import that class in your MainActivity...or activity in which you will use Gesture Detector

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have downloaded right platform versions and APIs in SDK manager, also you have to import correct libraries like:

```
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
```

besides, you have to implement following methods:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.gd.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```